# JQuery form submission and CakePHP controller

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using CakePHP and jQuery for my application.

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var str,fields;
    function showValues() {
        str = $("form").serialize();
        $("#results").text(str);
    }
    $("input").change(showValues);
    showValues();
    $(".submit").click(function (){
        alert(str);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/cake_1.2.1.8004/index.php/results/submit1",
            data: "str="+str,

            success: function(msg){
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
            }
        });//ajax
        return false;
    });//submit click
});//ready
```

While the alert inside click of submit function displays the entrie thing eg.. `_method=POST&name=a`

But when I post this value and retireve it in the controller its displaying only `_method=POST..`

My controller code is like,

```
function submit1($id = null) {
    echo "in ctrller ".$_POST['str'];
}
```

How to get the entire value in the controller and save it. Or is there any method to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

The *data* parameter for $.ajax call takes a string in this format:

```
param1=val1&param2=val2
```

now, you are already producing a string in this format using the $("form").serialize(); so the correct way to assign it is like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/cake_1.2.1.8004/index.php/results/submit1",
    data: str
  })
```

Your controller can then inspect the $_POST array for the parameter you are looking for.

Or print the POST'ed params as query string:

```
echo http_build_query($_POST);
```

Comment: Sorry the corerct function is http_build_query

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related to your problem (although knowing Cake, there's a good chance), but that's not the proper way to pass data from a form in Cake. What you should do is use `data[key]` as the key. Cake will take this and build an array called `$this->data` from it. If you use the FormHelper to build your HTML form, it will automatically set the `name` attribute to `data[Model][attribute]`, which you can access using `$this->data['Model']['attribute']` or pass it to a saving function, which is the actual intended usage.